# Rigorous error estimate for semi-discrete heat equation in bounded domain

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, parabolic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain in $\mathbb R^N$ and $u_h$ be a solution of 
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u_h -\Delta_h u_h = f(x) & \text{ in } \Omega_h\\
u_h=0 &\text{ in } \partial \Omega_h \setminus \Omega
\end{cases}$$ where $\Delta_h$ is the finite difference approximation of the Laplace operator, $\Omega_h$ is an extension of $\Omega$:
$$\Omega_h=\{x \in \mathbb R^N: dist(x,\Omega) < h \}.$$

How can we estimate the error $\Vert u_h - u\Vert_{L^\infty(\bar \Omega)}$, where $u$ is the solution of $$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u -\Delta u = f & \text{ in } \Omega\\
u=0 &\text{ in } \partial \Omega
\end{cases}$$
(i.e. the corresponding continuous problem)?

Comment: There are entire books on finite difference methods for PDEs. Also, it is by no means clear what "the" finite difference approximation of the Laplace operator is on a domain that is not a rectangle.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Yes, there are many books on the topic, but I cannot find a rigorous error estimate anywhere. For the definition, we extend the domain and set $u_h = 0$ in $\Omega_h \setminus \Omega$.